# Configure log directory for RStudio Server 1.0.44

Tags: r, rstudio-server

I'm running RStudio Server 1.0.44 on CentOS 7.

According to the [documentation](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200554766-RStudio-Server-Application-Logs), the server monitor logs are located at `/var/lib/rstudio-server/monitor/log`, but I'm unable to find them there. 
There is not `monitor` folder under `/var/lib/rstudio-server` folder, just `body`, `conf` and `proxy` subfolders, and there is not `rstudio-server.log` in the system. Maybe I missed something in the installation?

I would like to try setting the log folder manually, but I haven't found any way to set this property. Is this possible?

Any help would be appreciated.

P.S. Another user posted the same (unanswered) [question](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206713597-Configure-Log-Directory-for-RStudio) in the rstudio forum.

Comment: I noticed the same other Linux variants -- but it has been like this for years.  There is probably a toggle somewhere...

Comment: Are you running RStudio Server Pro?

Comment: @Jonathan No, I'm using the standard one.

Comment: I still have the same problem with latest 1.0.136 version of RStudio Server on CentOS 7 in a docker container...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my CentOS 7 Docker container, and with my RStudio Server version 1.0.136, I've managed to access to the logs using:

```
journalctl -u rstudio-server
```

Some more logs can be found using

```
journalctl -f
```

In a more general point of view, there are many logs in the following folder: `/var/log/anaconda`

According to RStudio Server support, another solution would be to launch `rstudio-server` with `--server-daemonize=0` in order for the output to be directly available on standard output & error.