# Unable to see the rstudio-server logs files

Tags: docker, centos7, rstudio-server, logfiles

I am running Rstudio-server inside a centos container. But I am not able to get the logs from the running container. I have already tried [RStudio Server - Application Logs](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200554766) as well as on [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40525722/configure-log-directory-for-rstudio-server-1-0-44), but they were not any help to me. I have tried various versions of Rstudio-servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my CentOS 7 Docker container, and with my RStudio Server version 1.0.136, I've managed to access to the logs using:

```
journalctl -u rstudio-server
```

Some more logs can be found using

```
journalctl -f
```

In a more general point of view, there are many logs in the following folder: /var/log/anaconda

According to RStudio Server support, another solution would be to launch rstudio-server with --server-daemonize=0 in order for the output to be directly available on standard output & error.

i performed on my machine and i got all the logs

[root@ccanalytics-dev-dev01 rksharma]# journalctl -u rstudio-server
-- Logs begin at Wed 2017-05-17 15:43:44 EDT, end at Fri 2018-01-12 03:49:17 EST. --
May 18 08:14:00 ccanalytics-dev-dev01.netlink.com systemd[1]: Starting RStudio Server...
May 18 08:14:00 ccanalytics-dev-dev01.netlink.com systemd[1]: Started RStudio Server.
May 18 08:16:02 ccanalytics-dev-dev01.netlink.com rserver[40106]: ERROR system error 13 (Permission denied) [user-value=admin]; OCCURRED AT: 
May 18 08:16:02 ccanalytics-dev-dev01.netlink.com rserver-pam[40159]: ERROR pam_authenticate failed: User not known to the underlying authent
May 18 08:44:16 ccanalytics-dev-dev01.netlink.com rserver[40106]: ERROR system error 13 (Permission denied) [user-value=rishabs]; OCCURRED AT
May 18 08:44:16 ccanalytics-dev-dev01.netlink.com rserver-pam[40193]: ERROR pam_authenticate failed: User not known to the underlying authent
May 23 05:17:06 ccanalytics-dev-dev01.netlink.com killall[20898]: rserver: no process found
May 23 05:17:06 ccanalytics-dev-dev01.netlink.com systemd[1]: rstudio-server.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
May 23 05:17:06 ccanalytics-dev-dev01.netlink.com systemd[1]: Unit rstudio-server.service entered failed state.
May 23 05:17:06 ccanalytics-dev-dev01.netlink.com systemd[1]: rstudio-server.service failed.
May 23 05:17:07 ccanalytics-dev-dev01.netlink.com systemd[1]: rstudio-server.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
May 23 05:17:07 ccanalytics-dev-dev01.netlink.com systemd[1]: Starting RStudio Server...
May 23 05:17:07 ccanalytics-dev-dev01.netlink.com systemd[1]: Started RStudio Server.
May 23 05:19:00 ccanalytics-dev-dev01.netlink.com systemd[1]: rstudio-server.service: main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
May 23 05:19:00 ccanalytics-dev-dev01.netlink.com killall[20956]: rserver: no process found
May 23 05:19:00 ccanalytics-dev-dev01.netlink.com systemd[1]: rstudio-server.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
May 23 05:19:00 ccanalytics-dev-dev01.netlink.com systemd[1]: Unit rstudio-server.service entered failed state.
May 23 05:19:00 ccanalytics-dev-dev01.netlink.com systemd[1]: rstudio-server.service failed.
May 23 05:19:00 ccanalytics-dev-dev01.netlink.com systemd[1]: rstudio-server.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
May 23 05:19:00 ccanalytics-dev-dev01.netlink.com systemd[1]: Starting RStudio Server...
May 23 05:19:00 ccanalytics-dev-dev01.netlink.com systemd[1]: Started RStudio Server.
May 23 05:22:25 ccanalytics-dev-dev01.netlink.com killall[20993]: rserver: no process found
May 23 05:22:25 ccanalytics-dev-dev01.netlink.com systemd[1]: rstudio-server.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
May 23 05:22:25 ccanalytics-dev-dev01.netlink.com systemd[1]: Unit rstudio-server.service entered failed state.
May 23 05:22:25 ccanalytics-dev-dev01.netlink.com systemd[1]: rstudio-server.service failed.
May 23 05:22:25 ccanalytics-dev-dev01.netlink.com systemd[1]: rstudio-server.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
May 23 05:22:25 ccanalytics-dev-dev01.netlink.com systemd[1]: Starting RStudio Server...
May 23 05:22:25 ccanalytics-dev-dev01.netlink.com systemd[1]: Started RStudio Server.
May 23 05:22:51 ccanalytics-dev-dev01.netlink.com systemd[1]: rstudio-server.service: main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
May 23 05:22:51 ccanalytics-dev-dev01.netlink.com killall[21022]: rserver: no process found
May 23 05:22:51 ccanalytics-dev-dev01.netlink.com systemd[1]: rstudio-server.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
May 23 05:22:51 ccanalytics-dev-dev01.netlink.com systemd[1]: Unit rstudio-server.service entered failed state.
May 23 05:22:51 ccanalytics-dev-dev01.netlink.com systemd[1]: rstudio-server.service failed.
May 23 05:22:51 ccanalytics-dev-dev01.netlink.com systemd[1]: rstudio-server.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
May 23 05:22:51 ccanalytics-dev-dev01.netlink.com systemd[1]: Starting RStudio Server...
May 23 05:22:51 ccanalytics-dev-dev01.netlink.com systemd[1]: Started RStudio Server.
May 23 05:23:10 ccanalytics-dev-dev01.netlink.com rsession-rksharma[21050]: ERROR session hadabend; LOGGED FROM: rstudio::core::Error

Comment: Thanks for quick answer!! but there is no directory named **monitor**, only directories **body** , **conf** and **proxy** are there inside `/var/lib/rstudio-server` directory.

Comment: according to the documents of r studio the default location of log files are :
/var/log/messages
/var/log/rstudio

try this one

Comment: I have already tried whatever is there on Rstudio-server documentation page and several other stackoverflow answers.
What do you mean by `logs file will be displayed to you if any log existed`? there are always logs generated if an application is running. In my case, logs are not getting saved anywhere.

Comment: try this

Help Menu -> Diagnostics -> Show Log Files

Comment: I have already checked this as well. there is no option **Show Log Files** instead there is an option **Request Logs**. That is also of no help to me.

Comment: Hey Rishabh, If you tried it yourself and were able to capture the logs successfully. It would be great if you could tell me the steps involved in order to reproduce the same, Thanks!

Comment: your edited answer is already there stackoverflow link, I have given in my question. Anyway when I executed this command--            `No journal files were found.
-- No entries --`

Comment: on your host machine if you will run the command you will get all the logs of your rstudio logs. i got all my logs

Comment: **_on your host machine_** you mean inside the docker container or the host machine(Outside Docker). because on host machine `journalctl` is not installed.

Comment: When I run the **Rstudio-server** using `--rserver-daemonize off`  then I am able to get the logs on the console itself. Although I wanted the logs in a file. Bdw thanks !!